# What is the best program to use for this graphic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation

This is an advertisement of changed opening hours for a clinic. I would like to widen my photographic skills to graphic designing as well.

Photoshop; The repetitive patterns and the text etc I feel can be done in Photoshop rather efficiently.

Illustrator; I feel this is where having an image is a hindrance. Since images are not vectors, and will not scale as well without losing quality. What I will miss about AI is the convenient snapping options. But I believe those can be set in PS as well.

I'm interested in an evaluation of my reasoning and some further inputs.

[image]

Comment: Illustrator: having an image is a hindrance????? Who said that??? Every vector application is good for it.

Comment: What is the intended output for the image? The answer to the question heavily depends on that. If you want to display this on the web or print it on a roll-up banner guides what software you should use.

Comment: @Danielillo- I mentioned that I am primarily experienced in photography, so I thought it would be obvious that I am not stating that what I know is correct. Each of my sentences starts with 'I feel' indicating that this is what I think but not something I am certain of. Please try to understand the question before leaving a response.

Comment: So If I am wrong, which I likely am, don't just state the obvious, explain it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done in either Photoshop or Illustrator, but since you appear to say you're doing the pattern in Photoshop, I'll say use what you know best and do everything in Photoshop.

Comment: I didn't say that, I said I feel it can be done in PS. While I know it can be done easier in AI. However I have not edited or played with images in AI. Are there downsides?

Comment: AI doesn't make this easier or harder. If we start a timer with somebody with good PS and AI skills, it would probably take about the same time to construct this.

Comment: It's not about time, it's about how well each program can handle image files. I'm really coming  from the standpoint of plebeian, so assume I know very little.

Comment: Photoshop works better with images if you need to adjust the image (photo resolution, size, contrast, light, adjust spots, etc) if you need anything like that AI cannot work. If the photo is 100% ready to be used for your purpose with no raster processing, there is really no argument for or against either PS or AI.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly stuff like this is what I needed to make my decision..words like raster are generally lost on me unless I hear someone put them in context.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a question of either Photoshop or Illustrator. This image can be done in both provided that the image does not need correcting.

However looking at the broader picture: Ultimately one needs both a photo manipulator and a tool that understands a page description langauge*. Having the tool also be able to do vector object manipulation is plus. So at the end of the day you need 2 software. If you use Adobe Stack then Photoshop + Illustrator or Photoshop + inDesign. However you could use any cobination of software for it.

* Photo manipulators do not understand page descriptions because they approach things with pixels in mind. Unfortunately page description languages don't work in a fixed grid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to graphic design, I am primarily a photographer. Could you explain what you mean by page description language in layman's terms? I have searched it and have a rough idea.